# gcc compiler NULL assignment doesn't assign NULL

Tags: linux, gcc, mingw-w64

I'm debugging someone elses library (AGAR) and I have come across a situation where where a pointer is assigned a NULL value on on the immediately following line of code it is not NULL.

The non NULL value is causing a seg fault!

I can't see the problem in the code.

```
    int AG_EventLoop(void)
    {
        AG_EventSource *src = AG_GetEventSource();
        AG_EventSink *es;
...
            for((es) = ((&src->epilogues)->tqh_first); (es) != NULL; (es) = ((es)->sinks.tqe_next)) {
                es->fn(es, &es->fnArgs);  // seg fault here should not have entered
            }
...
     }
```

In the for loop es is assigned the first item in the queue :

`(es) = ((&src->epilogues)->tqh_first);`

The debugger shows the values:

```
src->epilogues: 0x1bbd28
  tqh_first: 0x0
  tqh_last: 0x1bbd28
es: 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee
```

If tqh_first is 0x0 (NULL) where is the value 0xfeeefeeefeeefeee for es coming from?

The code only fails in MINGW64 and works as expected in Linux.

Comment: forgot to mention both es and tqh_first are AG_EventSink pointers.

Comment: The question is missing too much information and context.

Comment: Please don't comment your question. It should be edited instead.

Comment: I got fooled so many times by a debugger. You should check if the value that is displayed by the debugger for `src` is the actual value.

Comment: `(&src->epilogues)->tqh_first` looks suspicious to me. Are you sure you must take that address? (Because it implies that `rc->epilogues`  is not a pointer , so you could as well say `src->epilogues.qh_first`.) But try to boil it down to something more complete, and we may be able to help  you, unless you found the problem yourself by stripping it down to the core.